# ruby RestClient per request settings

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rest-client

I like [RestClient](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.3/RestClient) API very much but it looks to me that I can't configure proxy, timeouts, request hooks, ssl, etc. per request. So for example if I want to execute some requests concurrently in different threads, they may interfere between each other because I've changed some of the configuration.

Am I missing something? Is there a workaround as this seems to me a serious limitation.

Update:
Actually looking at the [Request](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.3/RestClient/Request#initialize-instance_method) class I think that only proxy configuration and `before_execution_procs` are global configuration. Most probably there would be workarounds possible with `before_execution_procs`. If you know how to set these per request, I'd be grateful.

example:

```
(1..10).each {
  Thread.new {
    RestClient.get(..., proxy: "some proxy", before_execution_hooks: [some, array, of, hooks])
  }
}
```

If I make it like:

```
(1..10).each {
  Thread.new {
    RestClient.proxy = "per request proxy"
    RestClient.add_before_execution_proc {...}
    RestClient.get(...)
  }
}
```

Then I'll end up with unknown proxy per request as well with multiple procs.

Comment: Please show us a code failing, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now set proxy as per request options

With [RestClient::Request](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/883903f5e5ae6c894db4e1271b3236301d881ee1/lib/restclient/request.rb) or with [RestClient::Resource](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/883903f5e5ae6c894db4e1271b3236301d881ee1/lib/restclient/resource.rb) which have both :proxy and :before_execution_proc options that override the global settings:

So the following code should be thread safe:

```
(1..10).each do
  Thread.new do
    RestClient::Resource.new(url, proxy: 'resquest specific', before_execution_proc: ...).get
    # or
    RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: 'http://...', proxy: ...)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like `:proxy` and `:before_execution_proc` are processed options in a later version of `rest-client`. But why should I use `RestClient::Resource`? I don't see why should I need such a wrapper.

Comment: Tested with 2.0.0.rc1, proxy does not need to be set globally. Accepting answer but still I can't see why `Resource` should be used instead of the `Request`.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I was using it like that already so did not check the use Request, I'm editing the answer so that it's complete